# R: How to have a monotonically increasing smoothing spline

Tags: r, visualization, spline

My question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447999/how-to-make-monotonic-increasing-smooth-spline-with-smooth-spline-function), but its answers did not really address my concerns.

```
dd <- structure(list(Score = c(0.00850444357692308, 0.020584329, 0.00850444357692308, 
0.030544489, 0.020584329, 0.0351414854615385, 0.030544489, 0.040504648, 
0.0351414854615385, 0.051128818, 0.040504648, 0.062416999, 0.051128818, 
0.07436919, 0.062416999, 0.086985392, 0.07436919, 0.099601594, 
0.086985392, 0.113545817, 0.099601594, 0.131474104, 0.113545817, 
0.14940239, 0.131474104, 0.17065073, 0.14940239, 0.193891102, 
0.17065073), Age = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 11, 11, 14, 14, 
16, 16, 23, 23, 26, 26, 31, 31, 44, 44, 46, 46, 53, 53, 56, 56
)), .Names = c("Score", "Age"), row.names = c("1", "2", "15", 
"3", "21", "4", "32", "5", "41", "11", "51", "14", "6", "16", 
"7", "23", "8", "26", "9", "31", "10", "44", "111", "46", "12", 
"53", "13", "56", "141"), class = "data.frame")

plot(x = dd$Age, y = dd$Score, pch = 16)
lines(smooth.spline(dd$Age, dd$Score), lty = 2, col = "red")
lines(spline(dd$Age, dd$Score, method = "hyman", n = 56), lty = 2)
```

[image]

My goal is to fit a smooth, monotonically increasing spline through my data (black dots). Using `smooth.spline` gives me a very smooth line to the naked eye (red). However, it's not constrained to be monotonically increasing (though it is in this case). To address the monotonicity issue, we turn to `spline`, in which we can specify the method to produce a monotonically increasing spline (dotted black), but clearly, it's very wiggly and not as smooth as the red.

I want a spline that has the monotonically increasing feature of `spline` (dotted black) but also the non-wiggliness of `smooth.spline` (red).

Is there a way to set the parameters for `smooth.spline` so that it'll always be monotonically increasing? Or the alternative is to play with some form of smoothing parameter so that `spline` will give a smoother fit?

Comment: Did you try `smooth.monotone` from `fda`?

Comment: I have not, but I will look into it.