# Fitting a monotonically increasing spline function using Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline, polynomial-approximations

I want to fit a monotonically increasing smooth spline function for a dataset

Code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0., 0.75, 1.8, 2.25, 3.75, 4.5, 6.45, 6.75, 7.5, 8.325, 10.875, 11.25, 12.525, 12.75, 15., 20.85, 21.]
    y = [2.83811035, 2.81541896, 3.14311655, 3.22373554, 3.43033456, 3.50433385, 3.66794514, 3.462296, 3.59480959,
         3.56250726, 3.6209845,  3.63034523, 3.68238915, 3.69096892, 3.75560395, 3.83545191, 3.90419498]

    plt.plot(x, y, '*')
    plt.show()
    f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
    yinp = f(x)
    plt.plot(x, yinp)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

The current fit looks like the above. I would like to know how to fit a monotonically increasing spline function.

I found an example in r posted here [How to make monotonic (increasing) smooth spline with smooth.spline() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447999/how-to-make-monotonic-increasing-smooth-spline-with-smooth-spline-function). I am not sure what's the appropriate function in the scipy library.

Suggestions will be really helpful.

EDIT:
I'm looking for something like the below ([ref.](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1795360-fitting-a-monotonically-increasing-spline-function))

[image]

EDIT 2:

I'm now using a smoothing spline function   scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x = np.array([0., 0.75, 1.8, 2.25, 3.75, 4.5, 6.45, 6.75, 
              7.5, 8.325, 10.875, 11.25, 12.525, 12.75, 15., 
              20.85, 21.])
y = np.array([2.83811035, 2.81541896, 3.14311655, 
              3.22373554, 3.43033456, 3.50433385, 
              3.66794514, 3.462296,   3.59480959, 
              3.56250726, 3.6209845,  3.63034523, 
              3.68238915, 3.69096892, 3.75560395, 
              3.83545191, 3.90419498])
              

spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0.05)
xs  = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=5)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'cyan', lw=1)
plt.show()
```

gives the following result

[image]

I could get the coeffs and knots of the spline using

```
    print(spl.get_coeffs())
    print(spl.get_knots())

    k = 3
    tck = splrep(xmean, ymean, k=k, s=0.09)
    knots = tck[0]
    coeffs = tck[1]
    print('knot points=', knots)
    print('coefficients=', coeffs)
```

But I am not sure how to use the coefficients and manually generate the function of the spline curve. Could someone please add a bit more detail to this?

For example, when we have 4 data points

```
x = [0., 0.75, 1.8, 2.25]
y = [2.83811035, 2.81541896, 3.14311655, 3.22373554]
```

I would like to print the piecewise polynomial function to understand how the spline function looks like.

Comment: how do you expect to fit monotonically increasing splines if your data isn't monotonically increasing?

Comment: @Nin17 Thanks for the reply. By excluding such points

Comment: @Nin17 Please check my edit

Comment: Hi @Natasha, can you add your final code?  I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `splrep` from scipy.interpolate and manually tweak its `s` parameter which controls the amount of smoothing.

EDIT: The definition of the spline function that `splrep` returns, in terms of knots and coefficients, is equivalent to `scipy.interpolate.BSpline`, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html

Comment: Thank you, could you please check my edit?

Comment: The splin function is defined like this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html